# Spring Remote, configure httpinvoker and JAX on the same server

Tags: spring, jax-ws, httpinvoker

I have a server running on tomcat exposing Spring services using HttpInvoker.

I have exposed the methods of 5 services using HTTPInvoker.

This works very well.

The spring configuration is described in a file named remoting-servlet.xml; and the remoting servlet (DispatcherServlet) is described in the web.xml.

I now have an additional need to expose one additional service using JAX-WS this time (I will have C# clients).

I will use Spring support to JAX-WS.

I have the option to use the default deployment, or to use JAX-WS RI's to deploy this additional service to the same server as the remoting servlet.

I would prefer this last solution, because I would have only one server providing the remote services (whether they are web services or httpinvokers).

My question is: is this possible?

I think that I can I put the 2 servlets on the same port. But my issue is that it seems to me that I will have to provide 2 different application contexts. One for the DispatcherServlet, and one for the WSSpringServlet.

Is that correct?

Is it possible to put the WSSpringServlet context definition to the same file as the one for the httpinvokers (remoting-servlet.xml)?

Many thanks

Gilles

Comment: Why not use Spring WS for this? Or simply use Spring to register the endpoints using the `SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter`.

Comment: If I use the SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter I have to specify a port. Do you mean, that in the removing-servlet.xml configuration file (which contains the configuration of the httpinvokers), I can simply add a SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter?

Comment: No you don't have to specify the port, that is for the client the `JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean`. The `SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter` detects `@WebService` annotated beans in the context and exports them.

Comment: Instead of using JAX-WS you can also use Spring WS (a different approach to develop your web service but that shouldn't matter).

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to follow the Spring documentation, which looks fairly simple, but cannot figure out why I cannot make it work. I have posted my code here to see if somebody could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632554/spring-jax-ws-support-exposing-web-service

Comment: Got it working by adding Service on my class (or adding the bean definition in the context xml file. Does this means that <context:component-scan base-package is not enough for Spring to manage WebService annotated beans?

Comment: component scan only picks yp `@Component` annotated beans. `@WebService` isn't a `@Component`. You could add an include filter for that specific annotation.